# How to create binary grid mat efficiently in OpenCV2?

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi，I'm trying to create something like a chessboard matrix in OpenCV, like

```
|0  |255|0  |255|0  |
|255|0  |255|0  |255|
|0  |255|0  |255|0  |
|255|0  |255|0  |255|
```

My method is

`Mat tmp = (Mat_<double>(2, 2) << 255, 0, 0, 255);
 Mat bwMask = cv::repeat(tmp, cols, rows);`

I wonder if there is better way to do this.

I do this because I need a way to resize image twice the size, while keep missing value to zero instead of interpolating. 
So if there is way to do that directly I will appreciate some enlightenment a lot.

Comment: May be just remove every second row/col ?

Comment: I still need to keep the size for later smoothing operation